# jQuery | Ajax | xhr.statusText:'OK' vs xhr.status:200

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

En el ajax de jQuery, necesito un `xhr.statusText:'OK'` y me arroja un `'success'`.

Me arroja también un `xhr.status:200` sirve para lo mismo?

- Ejemplo:

`if (xhr.statusText == 'OK' || xhr.status == 200) {
    // Ok! It works! Let's do something...
    });`

Comment: Gracias Rubén por las correcciones!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado,

200 es la respuesta HTTP STATUS OK de un request http, agrego como referencia la lista de codigos de estado http: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP

Siempre es mejor, comparar codigos de estado, y no su texto descriptivo, ya que el mismo podria ser modificado por el servidor que lo envia.

En una llamada ajax, si el xhr.status == 200, quiere decir que la respuesta del servidor fue correcta, pero debes analizar el contenido para validar son los datos devueltos son los que necesitas.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por modificar tu respuesta y tu contribucion al sitio, saludos!